# Trying to pass remove_reference as a function parametar

Tags: c++

So, I'm doing my homework, and as a part of the code I need to create a function with 3 parameters, first two being pointers or iterators that form a certain block of elements, and a third parameter which is a function with one parameter, and that parameter is the same type as the elements of the blocks between two pointers or iterators.

It works if I use only

```
decltype<*p1+*p1>
```

where p1 is a pointer to the block of elements, but it wont work if the elements are complex numbers.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work

```
template <typename Type>
bool Fun(Type p1,Type p2,bool(*f)(std::remove_reference<decltype(p1)>::type))
```

and says the following:  error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [iterator traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)? They're in the standard library for a reason...

```
template <typename InputIt>
bool Fun(
    InputIt first, 
    InputIt last,
    bool(*f)(std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type)
)
```

Also, you could consider "duck typing" the function parameter:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename F>
bool Fun(
    InputIt first, 
    InputIt last,
    F f
)
{
    using std::iterator_traints<InputIt>::value_type;
    value_type x { whatever() };
    do_something_with(f(x));
}
```

which often lets you do things you actually want to but had not expected to try...

Answer (score 1):

Functions which act on iterators in a generic way should also template on the function parameter:

```
template<class Iter, class Func>
bool do_stuff(Iter begin, Iter end, Func&& func) {
    // ...
}
```

This has the following benefits:

- The function now accepts lambdas and other objects that overload the function operator
- The compiler can in-line the function call because it knows what function is getting called at compile-time
- If `func` takes the parameter by reference, by const reference, or by using it to construct the actual parameter, the code will still compile.

Answer (score 0):

That error message occurs because the compiler cannot figure out what it should be expecting. If you tell the compiler that it should expect the identifier `type` to refer to a type, then the the code compiles:

```
template <typename Type>
bool Fun(Type p1,Type p2,bool(*f)(typename std::remove_reference<decltype(p1)>::type))
                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Lots of people found this to be too much typing (in C++11), so C++14 introduced a shorter name for the same thing:

```
template <typename Type>
bool Fun(Type p1,Type p2,bool(*f)(std::remove_reference_t<decltype(p1)>))
                                                       ^^              ^.. no "::type"
```

Still... don't you want `decltype(*p1)`, not the type of the iterator itself?